# An extra println in the main thread causes Rust to perform different results

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I found a phenomenon when learning Rust tokio multithreading, I don't know why。

Here is the code.

```
use std::{thread, time::Duration};

use chrono::Local;

fn now() -> String {
    Local::now().format("%F %T").to_string()
}

async fn async_task(i: u64) {
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(i));
    println!("{}.async task {}!", now(), i);
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        tokio::spawn(async_task(i));
    }
    println!("{}.main thread", now());
}
```

I ran the code and found that each 10 async tasks were executed. Result was live below

```
2023-09-05 22:08:05.async task 0!
2023-09-05 22:08:05.main thread
2023-09-05 22:08:06.async task 1!
2023-09-05 22:08:07.async task 2!
2023-09-05 22:08:08.async task 3!
2023-09-05 22:08:09.async task 4!
2023-09-05 22:08:10.async task 5!
2023-09-05 22:08:11.async task 6!
2023-09-05 22:08:12.async task 7!
2023-09-05 22:08:13.async task 8!
2023-09-05 22:08:14.async task 9!
```

When I comment out the `println` code in the `main` thread, only a few of the tasks will be executed.

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        tokio::spawn(async_task(i));
    }
    // println!("{}.main thread", now());
}
```

Result was live below

```
2023-09-05 22:10:51.async task 0!
2023-09-05 22:10:52.async task 1!
```

I've tried this many times, and every time this difference occurs. On every attempt, code that does not comment out `println` executes all async tasks, and the other one does not.

I really don't understand why a `println` could make such a big difference. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help.

Comment: *"I really don't understand why a `println` could make such a big difference"* - because `println` takes a long time. I suspect it's a timing thing, that at the end of `main()`, `tokio` waits for all spawned tasks, but some of them aren't done being spawned yet. Or something similar.

Comment: Also: don't use `thread::sleep`, it blocks the entire async runtime. Use `tokio::sleep().await` instead.

Comment: Finomnis said, "`println` takes a long time." IDK about rust specifically, but in other languages, the equivalent of `println!(...)` doesn't _merely_ take time. It also is a [_yield point_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yield_(multithreading)), and in a multi-threaded program, it locks and unlocks at least one mutex. Both of those things can have significant side effects in a program with threads that are not properly synchronized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real reason your code behaves weirdly is because you use `std::thread::sleep` instead of `tokio::time::sleep`.

It's important when working with async functions that you **never** block. Async reactors are **non-preemptive**, meaning they can only schedule between tasks at `.await` points. That means, if you `std::thread::sleep`, you block the entire program. That's also why in your working program, the output doesn't always get printed in the correct order, although the timing should be an entire second between each print.

If you replace `std::thread::sleep` with `tokio::time::sleep`, you will get a consistent behaviour (although it is probably not the behaviour you desire):

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use chrono::Local;

fn now() -> String {
    Local::now().format("%F %T").to_string()
}

async fn async_task(i: u64) {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(i)).await;
    println!("{}.async task {}!", now(), i);
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    for i in 0..10 {
        tokio::spawn(async_task(i));
    }
    println!("{}.main thread", now());
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(2500)).await;
}
```

```
2023-09-05 16:39:25.main thread
2023-09-05 16:39:25.async task 0!
2023-09-05 16:39:26.async task 1!
2023-09-05 16:39:27.async task 2!
```

Why so? Because when `main` finishes, tokio cancels all leftover tasks. But again, tokio can only schedule at `.await` points, so in your 'working' example, tokio still tries to cancel the tasks, but isn't successful because they never hit an `.await` point. So it 'seems' like tokio is waiting for them, but that's actually not true.

The simplest way to solve this is to not have the `main` function end. (actually this is the only way that comes to my mind)

There are multiple ways to achieve that. In your case, it seems to me that your intention is to wait for all subtasks to finish, and then to end the program. This can be done by awaiting the join handles:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use chrono::Local;

fn now() -> String {
    Local::now().format("%F %T").to_string()
}

async fn async_task(i: u64) {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(i)).await;
    println!("{}.async task {}!", now(), i);
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut joinhandles = Vec::new();
    for i in 0..10 {
        joinhandles.push(tokio::spawn(async_task(i)));
    }

    println!("{}.main thread", now());

    for joinhandle in joinhandles {
        joinhandle.await.unwrap();
    }
}
```

```
2023-09-05 16:47:23.main thread
2023-09-05 16:47:23.async task 0!
2023-09-05 16:47:24.async task 1!
2023-09-05 16:47:25.async task 2!
2023-09-05 16:47:26.async task 3!
2023-09-05 16:47:27.async task 4!
2023-09-05 16:47:28.async task 5!
2023-09-05 16:47:29.async task 6!
2023-09-05 16:47:30.async task 7!
2023-09-05 16:47:31.async task 8!
2023-09-05 16:47:32.async task 9!
```

That said, awaiting them one by one is a little tedious and also prevents propagating errors immediately. Instead, you could use [`futures::future::try_join_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.try_join_all.html):

```rust
use std::time::Duration;

use chrono::Local;

fn now() -> String {
    Local::now().format("%F %T").to_string()
}

async fn async_task(i: u64) {
    tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(i)).await;
    println!("{}.async task {}!", now(), i);
}
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    // Same as the for-loop in the earlier example,
    // just more compact and functional
    let joinhandles = (0..10)
        .map(|i| tokio::spawn(async_task(i)))
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    println!("{}.main thread", now());

    futures::future::try_join_all(joinhandles).await.unwrap();
}
```

```
2023-09-05 16:56:14.main thread
2023-09-05 16:56:14.async task 0!
2023-09-05 16:56:15.async task 1!
2023-09-05 16:56:16.async task 2!
2023-09-05 16:56:17.async task 3!
2023-09-05 16:56:18.async task 4!
2023-09-05 16:56:19.async task 5!
2023-09-05 16:56:20.async task 6!
2023-09-05 16:56:21.async task 7!
2023-09-05 16:56:22.async task 8!
2023-09-05 16:56:23.async task 9!
```